# Will empty value in JSON hurt backend or front-end design

Tags: json

I'm designing JSON structure for communication between front-end and backend.

As you can see on the JSON structure. The `couldHave` node value is empty.
Should I remove this node from the JSON totally? 
Or leave it as an empty value.

I can think of if I remove them entirely. The size will be reduced.

```
"structureNames":{  
   "List View":"default_related_queue_contracts_list_view"
},
"whereClause":{  
   "mustHave":[  
      {  
         "fieldName":"Status",
         "comparison":"eq",
         "value":"5"
      }
   ],
   "couldHave":[  

   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though having empty array`[]` will not be an issue, apart from the size you have mentioned. But if you don't send this node at all, then in cases where you need to access value of `couldHave`, will start throwing error like `Cannot read value <key> of undefined`. So, it's better if you send an empty array.

To handle such cases in client, you will anyway write something to handle this `undefined` case. Or you will use it something like 
`var a = whereClause.couldHave || [];`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, leaving an empty node will not cause any problems if your front-end is not trying to parse that empty node ...however, it is always good practice to have at least a default empty value... that way your front end can call a function **handleMissingInformation()** when ever an empty node value is referenced.